# Custom photoshop script to combine files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, automation, script

I've created a few drawings of characters with blank faces and several different facial expressions that I intended to simply put over the drawing of the blank-faced character (face pictures have correct transperency).

However now I find myself with a lot of files and too lazy to manually do each one. Is it possible to create a Photoshop script which would open an image, import another image as a layer, based on the file's name, and save the whole thing? And then be able to do this for all my files?

Comment: Sure. If you have experience with PS scripting it's going to be quite straightforward.  [Here's the PS JS scripting guide](https://blog.cutterman.cn/assets/files/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref.pdf)

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy, thank you!